# How to set iCloud Root in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios6, icloud

here i created local root for document storage but i want to implement iCloud.so i need to create iCloud  Root and also i will check if iCloud available or not. if it is possible to create like Method. here i added my local root method code

```
- (NSURL *)localRoot {

if (_localRoot != nil) {
    return _localRoot;
}


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *artdirectoryPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Me"];


_localRoot=[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:artdirectoryPath];


return _localRoot;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find the iCloud "root" directory using:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
```

If you have only one ubiquity container for your app, you can pass `nil` for the argument, otherwise you must pass the container identifier.

You can also use this to check if iCloud is available to your app-- if it returns `nil`, you can't use iCloud. It's not the best way to check for availability though, because it can block for a while. For a quick, non-blocking check, use this:

```
id token = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
```

And then be sure to observe `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` in case the availability changes.

However: this is nowhere near enough to start using iCloud for documents. You can't just read/write files in that directory and have iCloud do the right thing. At an absolute minimum you'll need:

- `NSMetadataQuery` to find documents that exist on the cloud server but are not downloaded locally.
- `-[NSFileManager startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:]` to tell iCloud to begin downloading documents you've found with the metadata query.
- Coordinated access via `NSFileCoordinator`, and notifications of changes via `NSFilePresenter`.

Apple has a lot of documentation, and videos from WWDC that will help with this.